# How to export all Sapper routes into static files?

Tags: static, svelte, sapper

When I run `yarn run export` / `npm run export`, only one of my routes get exported as a separate static html file. I want all of them to get exported, into their own `.html` files.

Am I missing a setting?

The only route exporting is `/login`

You can check this in this repo (i cannot provide samples, since I don't know what causes this issue): https://github.com/useverto/verto

Comment: Did my answer help, or did I not quite understand the question correctly?

Comment: yes, sorry, i just figured out on my own, than came back and saw you response. thanks :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `sapper export` is run you'll see that it first builds the app, runs it, and then crawls the links it finds to determine the routes it can export.

https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#How_it_works

Because the `Nav` component in your app only exposes `/` and `/login` as links when `loggedIn` is false, the export will only see and follow those links. The `/trade` and `/gallery` links in your app are only rendered once `loggedIn` is true, so they'll not be seen by the export.

You can add other routes to be exported with the `--entry` option to the `sapper export` command. So in your case you could change the export command in `package.json` to something like...

```
"export": "sapper export --legacy --entry '/ trade gallery'",
```